# Background service is freezing/lagging android app

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast

I have been developing an android application in which there is a service and I want to **run it for ever**.

I am using a **broadcast receiver** to get **screen on-off intents** inside **oncreate of service** and using an **alarm manager**  which starts the **service itself after every 25 seconds inside onstartcommand** and also performing my other operations in onstartcommand. I have put all the code in **onstartcommand inside an thread**. But the problem is once the service in running for **some hours** in **background** and I **reopen the app** the app starts **lagging and becomes very slow**. Before starting the service the app works very fine.

The Brief of my code is as follows -

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    AlarmManager alarmManagerMain;
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    Thread t;
    Thread thread;

        @Override
    public void onCreate()  {
        super.onCreate();
        t = new Thread(() -> {
            HandleReceiver();
        });
        t.start();
        CreateNotificationChannel();
        startNotification();
    }

    private void HandleReceiver() {
        try {
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
            intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
            receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
                    {
                        // ...
                        // My Code
                        // ...
                        // Starting Service to call onStartCommand
                        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
                        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                        {
                            startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            startService(serviceIntent);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))
                    {
                        // ...
                        // My Code
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            };
            MyService.this.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
        }
        catch (Exception ignore) { }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Runnable runnable = () -> {
            if(allowNotificationAndAlerts)
            {
                // My Code
            }
            // This function is to start the service even after the system kills it
            startAlarm();
        };
        thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void startAlarm()
    {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) MyService.this.getSystemService(Service.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyService.this, MyBroadCastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyService.this, 1, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 25);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopForeground(false);
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

My questions are -

1. How can I **optimize** the service as to run it for ever in background without causing the lag in app
2. Is there any way to get **screen on off intents** by **system** or anything else instead of **running the service** with **broadcast receiver**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer
I was able to solve it by removing "android:process=:remote" line from service in manifest and changing shared preferences to database the issue was maybe because shared preferences are not process safe